# How do I set up GUIMiner to use my cpu?

Tags: miner-configuration, cpu-mining, guiminer

I'm using GUIMiner. It's not using my CPU. My CPU is at a very low utilization (~10%).

What I can do to use my CPU?

Why isn't CPU mining turned on by default?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does this have to do with bitcoind?

Comment: What coin are you mining?  For most coins, CPU mining costs far more in electricity than the revenue you can expect to get from it.  That's why it isn't on by default.

Answer (score 2):

CPU mining ended in 2011. You will earn less than what the electricity costs, so the more you mine the more money you lose. You will never earn the minimum amount required to cash out from a pool, so you actually won't be earning anything at all, just burning electricity.

This is why CPU mining is disabled, and why noone should use it.